# Does CSS formatting of <h1>, <h2> tags have effect on search ranking?

Tags: seo, css

I have a web page where I made some style into `<h1>`, `<h2>` tags, will it make some effect on my SEO ranking?

Comment: This question has been asked several times in several forms. I've linked one of a few that already exist on the site.

Answer (score 1):

No, CSS styles only affect the perception of the user, it doesn't affect bots, crawlers, etc.

Of course an attractive site will please more users and those will will come back, link and share, and that will affect your ranking.

Comment: Just being pedantic but *most* CSS will not have an effect. If you are using CSS to do some form of cloaking etc however it probably will be frowned on and affect your SEO ranking.